# Can I change my iMac brightness sensitivity?

Tags: imac

My iMac has a feature which automatically adjusts the brightness of the screen. This is a great feature when day turns to night, and when I turn the room lights off.

However, my iMac faces a window -- every time the sun goes beneath a cloud, the screen dims. Once the sun appears again, the screen goes to full brightness. It seems odd that the screen would change brightness so suddenly, when it takes my retina a full 5/10 minutes to adjust. Obviously not a pleasant experience.

So my question: **is it possible to adjust the sensitivity of the detection, or to slow down the response when changing brightness?**

Comment: You could try using [flux](http://justgetflux.com/) instead of adjusting brightness.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, unfortunately. 
Apple doesn't give us any settings, but Turn ON/OFF.
I suppose You can hack it, but it's not worth time for such a simple problem.
Maybe it's easier to change place for computer or Turn this feature Off?